# Execute automatic change connected displays in Windows 8

Tags: c#, batch-file, windows-8, hardware, nvidia

**Short version**

How do I automate changing multiple display settings? NVIDIA, 3x monitors (2x DVI and 1x HDMI), GPU only supports 2 active monitors.

---

**Long version**

So I have a `NVIDIA GeForce GTX 560 Ti` which can run two displays simultaneously. It has two **DVI** connections and one **HDMI**. I often swap from using my two desktop monitors and connect only one of the desktop monitors plus my TV using **HDMI**.

I would like to automate the change back and forward using a batch script or other program instead of using the windows control panel (Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Display\Screen Resolution) or the NVIDIA Control Panel.

I found some documentation on using "`rundll32.exe`, `NvCpl.dll`, `dtcfg` ...." etc. This did not work at all. Nothing happens for any parameters I use from the NVIDIA PDF documentation. Does anyone have an example that works? I have tried this on Windows 7 as well.

I have tried to use **WMI** to see if the monitor is there, but it only shows the two active monitors. It does not show the third inactive monitor.

I have tried `EnumDisplayDevices` from **User32.dll**, but this only returns the two active monitors.

How can I get this working?

I would like to get this working in C#, so I can use it with changing audio device as well :)

Comment: Did you get this working? I am facing a similar problem. rundll32.exe command did not work for me either. I tried the same on WinXP and it works. Did you try the sample application for control panel API in WinXP compatibility mode?

Comment: No, I still have not found a way to do this.

Comment: Did you try [this](http://developer.nvidia.com/nvapi)?

Comment: Have no tried this one, lacked C# examples on google results and was wondering if anyone have examples of this in C++ or other languages to do a screen change, like I described in the question :)

Comment: This [example](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/matthew_van_eerde/) explains ChangeDisplaySettingsEx function in the Win32 API. This [example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/178027/How-to-create-a-display-switcher-for-Windows-XP) shows how to obtain inactive displays. You should probably look at them

Answer (score 1):

Although this is may not meet your requirements, I did run in to this problem when using my laptop to power several monitors, and I ended up using the Display Profiles feature in [UltraMon](http://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/tour/display_profiles.asp).  I never [scripted it](http://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/tour/scripting.asp) or used [their SDK](http://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/developers.asp), but I do know that they do support automation and SDK access.

Note: I am in no way affiliated with UltraMon, I just used their product and found it to meet my needs.