# How to change 3rd monitor programmatically

Tags: windows, automation, multiple-monitors, video-card

When I'm using my laptop, I use 3 displays:

1. The laptop display
2. A second monitor (connected through VGA)
3. A TV (connected through HDMI)

My videocard doesn't support 3 monitors, so I'm constantly switching from 2 to 3: when I'm on the computer, I use the 2nd monitor, and when I want to watch some movies, etc. I use the 3rd.

I currently have to go to *Screen Resolution*, select the monitor that is not in use, and choose *Extend desktop to this display*.

**Is there a way I can automate it?**

Is there any command-line tool, or any Windows API that allows doing it?

**Edit:**
[Display Changer](http://12noon.com/) seems to do what I need, but the problem is that it only detects the working monitors. The 3rd monitor (which isn't currently in use) isn't detected, so I can't attach it.

Comment: I finally ended up buying a laptop with a Haswell processor. It includes the Intel HD 4600 which supports 3 displays ;)

Answer (score 1):

A bit of RE on DisplaySwitch.exe shows that it calls

```
SetDisplayConfig(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, 0x888)
```

to set it to Extended on my computer.

From there, a little digging around got me to the [SetDisplayConfig](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff569533%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) documentation obviously and also [this SO page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6590939/how-to-set-display-settings-to-extend-mode-in-windows-7-using-c) with some example code that queries your current display state and adds the actual flags to change them if you want to do so.

Answer (score 0):

I answered a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12547329/execute-automatic-change-connected-displays-in-windows-8/13212539#13212539) with suggestion to try [UltraMon](http://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/tour/display_profiles.asp) or use their SDK, but you can also hit the Win32 API directly with [`ChangeDisplaySettingsEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183413%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  Another user, [Sai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/822170/sai), gave an reference to an [example showing use of the function](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/178027/How-to-create-a-display-switcher-for-Windows-XP).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Let me take a look at those links :)

Comment: UltraMoon profiles work for me. The only downside is that all the opened windows I had are placed into the 1st monitor once I switch from profiles.

Comment: @OscarMederos, I have noticed that issue with RDP as well.  I am not sure if it is an UltraMon issue or a more widespread one.

Comment: I'll wait to see if someone posts another answer. If not, I'll just accept this one, since I'm looking for a more scripting solution :)