# How can I programmatically attach/detach displays in Windows 10?

Tags: windows

I'm wondering if there's a good way to automate changing my display configuration in Windows 10?

I have 3 monitors attached, and I find myself wanting to configure my system in one of 3 ways:

- All monitors set up to extend the desktop.
- Only my central (largest) monitor enabled, others both disabled.
- Only my right-most monitor enabled, others both disabled (I think hook up a spare HDMI cable on my center monitor to my laptop, and the monitor automatically switches to that input).

Manually, this involves opening the Display Settings panel, selecting the monitors, and either marking them as "Disconnected" or "Extend desktop on this display".

Is there some nice, scripting-friendly way to do this? I'm more comfortable doing this sorta thing on Linux, where I'd whip up a quick shell script to call the `xrandr` command a few times, or something like that...

Comment: I've never used more than two monitors so I don't know how the UI would look for that, but is Windows key + P not suitable for your purposes?

Comment: The information in https://stackoverflow.com/q/15031687/62576 doesn't help?

Comment: Thanks, @KenWhite, the [Display Changer](http://12noon.com/) tool referenced in that question does the trick nicely.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change 3rd monitor programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15031687/how-to-change-3rd-monitor-programmatically)